# Что сделать, чтобы vk не блокировал переход по ссылке?

Tags: вконтакте, dns, ddns

Есть сайт на домашнем компьютере (ip белый динамический) и настроенный [динамический dns](https://www.noip.com). Проблема в том, что если я пересылаю такую ссылку через vk.com, он блокирует переход с сообщением

> #### Потенциально вредоносная ссылка
>
> Ссылка, по которой Вы попытались перейти, ведёт на сайт, расположенный на бесплатном хостинге.
>
> Обычно такие сайты используются спамерами и мошенниками для перенаправления на потенциально опасные сайты, а также могут содержать вирусы.
>
> **ВКонтакте** всегда заботится о Вашей безопасности!

Причём, в этом сообщении даже нет кнопки для принудительного перехода:

[image: скриншот]

**Что можно сделать, чтобы vk не блокировал переход?**

---

Полная последовательность действий:

1. Есть ссылка через [noip](https://www.noip.com), типа такой: `http://smth.ddns.net:5157` (имя `smth` ненастоящее).
2. Переслать её через личные сообщения в vk.
3. Там она стандартно подменится на `https://vk.com/away.php?to=http%3A%2F%2Fsmth.ddns.net%3A5157&cc_key=`
4. При переходе по такой ссылке вместо редиректа выставлена заглушка.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79984/discussion-on-question-by-qwertiy----vk----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать сокращатель ссылок, но из тех, которые не блокируется vk.

Лично я воспользовался https://goo.gl, но его скоро закроют. И ещё стоит обратить внимание, что гугл в некоторых случаях сам может не любить подобные ссылки (например, аналогичную ссылку с *.redirectme.net он заблокировал сам).

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант создать страницу в GitHub Pages и делать редирект с помощью JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>REDIRECT Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div><span>Redirecting...</span></div>

<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location.href = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI"
    }, 3)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Создать репозиторий в GitHub
2. Активировать GitHub Pages в Settings
3. Создать файл index.html с содержимым как в верхнем листинге

Ссылку на страницу в GitHub Pages можно посмотреть там же в настройках.

[image: GitHub Settings Screenshot]

Я делал такое с heroku